# print the sequence of size n in which every term is sum of previous three terms?

Tags: python

### my Code

```
arr = [0 for i in range(9)]
arr[0] = 1
for i in range(1,9):
    j = i-1
    count = 0
    sum = 0
    while (j>=0 and count < 3):
        sum = sum + arr[j]
        j = j - 1
        count = count + 1
    arr[i] = sum
for i in range(0,9):
    print(arr[i])
```

### output is

1 1 2 4 7 13 24 44 81

### Expected Output is

1 1 1 3 5 9 17 31 57

Comment: why Expected is 1 before 3. first time 1 0 0...., then 1 1 0 0 ..., thne 1 1 2 0 0 ... is it right?

Answer (score 0):

You can use dynamic programming:

```
def seq(n):
    r=[1,1,1]
    for i in range(3, n):
        r.append(r[i-1] + r[i-2] +r[i-3])
    print(' '.join(map(str,r)))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can obstain that using a modified version of the code you use to calculate a Fibonacci sequence. This is using recursion:

```
import functools

@functools.lru_cache()
def sequence3(n):
    if n <= 0:
        raise ValueError(str(n) + " must be strictly positive")
    return 1 if n <= 2 else 2 if n == 3 else sum([sequence3(n-i) for i in range(1,4)])

number_of_elements = 10
print([sequence3[x] for x in range(1, number_of_elements+1)])
```

Answer (score 0):

You don’t need to keep the whole sequence. The last 3 elements suffice. Because the numbers get big (into the GNU MP realm) very quickly, let’s also extend the task by specifying that we don’t want any unnecessary calculations to happen, i.e., whatever is calculated must be also printed.

```py
def sequence(n):
  data = [1, 1, 1]
  for i in range(min(3, n)):
    yield data[i]
  for i in range(3, n):
    s = sum(data)
    yield s
    data[i % 3] = s

def print_sequence(n):
  for s in sequence(n):
    print(s)

print_sequence(100)
```